# What does this sequence of numbers represent?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46, 56

There is one specific answer I'm looking for, but you could come up with other things that logically work out.

Comment: This? [OEIS A000124](https://oeis.org/A000124)

Comment: Hi there! I recommend checking out [Number Sequence Puzzles - What (Not) To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do) as this is on OEIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of running sequence and result:

> 0+1=1
> 1+1=2
> 2+2=4
> 3+4=7
> 4+7=11
>
> and so on...

Comment: First time on this website, via my mobile, so really don't know how to put return properly... Thanks for the edit...

Comment: No problem!! The formatting can be a bit weird, >! is a spoiler and for a line break you can put two spaces on the end of a line :)

Comment: Yes, that's it.